# -bash: cd: Resources: No such file or directory

Tags: python, terminal, directory

the directory /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ contains the following four elements:
Headers  Python  Resources  Versions

When I try to cd into either Headers, Python or Resources (e.g. cd Resources), I get an error message telling me that the element does not exist (e.g.: "-bash: cd: Resources: No such file or directory").

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use autocompletion on TAB key press — maybe names contain some whitespace (less probably)
2. Check `ls -l` output — maybe these directories are just broken symbolic links